# How many combinations of RGB values need to represent a grayscale color?

Tags: colors, combinations, rgb

I know that grayscale color is produced by this equation `(R+G+B)/3` and it's also known that it's not possible to reverse this and find the actual RGB color that produced the greyscale.

But how many possible combinations are there to produce same Greyscale color? For example for values `0,0,90` and `90,0,0` the grayscale value for both pairs is equal to **30** and so for `45,45,0`.

I think that the equation (2) below is true but i'n not sure.

`(R+G+B)/3=Grey` (1)

`R+G+B=3*Grey` (2)

Let's suppose Grey=1 so from (1) we get R+G+B=3 so

[image]

getting 10 possible combinations because we get 4+3+2+1 rows, more specifically `Grey+1` first elements

So from this `n(n+1)/2` replacing `n` with `(3*Grey)+1` we finaly get

`(9*Grey*[Grey+1]/2) + 1` (2)

Comment: Gray is R=G=B, so it depends on how much value can take R (or G, or B). On a 8-bit per channel (and full range) you have 256 grays, on a 10-bit per channel you have 1024 grays, etc. Note: technically, lower values are whites, and higher values are blacks, there is no real standard on where you should set the "black point"

Comment: Worth noting that gray has different equations, for practical purposes and in the case of the ubiquitous sRGB, the relative luminance equation is as follows: `Y = 0.2126R + 0.7152G + 0.0722B`

Comment: Yes, you're looking for the `k+1` triangular number for `k = R+G+B`. But you have to remember that for a given grayscale value, you have to count not only `Gray*3`, but also `Gray*3+1` and `Gray*3-1` since those values will also round to `Gray`.